# How to move block functions into .inc file?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a module that is getting pretty large and I want to move the functions that define blocks into another file to better organize my module.

I did this:

1. Moved those functions ( `_block_configure`, `_block_info`, `_block_view`, etc) to `includes/blocks.inc` in my module.
2. Put `files[] = includes/blocks.inc` in my .info file

This doesn't work though - the blocks disappear when I do this.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The files directive is used to include files containing classes, check [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/542202).
You could include the file in the .module file.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/blocks.inc';
```

**Edit**: Included the other solutions added by @Beebee and @Jimajamma in the answer:

```
require_once  drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodulename') . '/includes/blocks.inc';
module_load_include('inc', 'MY_MODULE', 'FILE_NAME');
// This method is including a file residing in the module folder not in a subdirectory.
```

Comment: or you can also use ['drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodulename)'](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) as a prefix instead of `__DIR__` but I don't see anything wrong with either way.

Comment: Thanks. I put that require at the top of my .module file and it works smoothly. I was actually looking at the page you suggest, but didn't realize it is *only* for classes. Thanks.

Comment: drupal also has a helper function https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7 that does all of this for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [hook_hook_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_hook_info/7).

> Normally hooks do not need to be explicitly defined. However, by
>   declaring a hook explicitly, a module may define a "group" for it.
>   Modules that implement a hook may then place their implementation in
>   either $module.module or in $module.$group.inc. If the hook is located
>   in $module.$group.inc, then that file will be automatically loaded
>   when needed. In general, hooks that are rarely invoked and/or are very
>   large should be placed in a separate include file, while hooks that
>   are very short or very frequently called should be left in the main
>   module file so that they are always available.

In your case it should be,

```
/**
* Implements hook_hook_info().
*/
function mymodule_hook_info() {
  $hooks['block_info'] = array(
    'group' => 'block',
  );
  $hooks['block_configure'] = array(
    'group' => 'block',
  );
  $hooks['block_view'] = array(
    'group' => 'block',
  );
  return $hooks;
}
```

Then you should place those hook functions into a file called mymodule.block.inc and the same file should be available in the module directory.

For more info/caveats on this hook go [here](http://nodesforbreakfast.com/article/2012/02/20/organize-your-module-code-hookhookinfo-drupal-7).

Comment: `hook_hook_info` sounds great, but if you dig a little deeper, you'll see the limitations. Try to do that block thing in two modules and you'll see, that it won't work anymore. This is because the info provided by using this hook, is aggregated over all modules (see [module_hook_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_hook_info/7)), so that instead of `'group' => 'blocks'` you'll end up with `'group' => array(0 => 'block', 1 => 'block')`. This will fail as you can immediately see on the block page. I would use this with extreme caution.