# Moving functions in block module to inc file

Tags: 7, hooks, blocks

I have searched *everywhere* for an answer to this question, and have found little to no help on the subject.

The closest question to my own would be this, but the answer for it is a bit different than what I'm looking for:
[How to move block functions into .inc file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77545/how-to-move-block-functions-into-inc-file)

Here is my code for the most part (everything removed that wasn't necessary):

```
<?php

function custom_giggity_block_info(){
  $block['custom_giggity'] = array(
    'info' => t('Custom giggity'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $block;
}

function custom_giggity_block_view($delta = ''){
  $block = array();
  if($delta == 'custom_giggity'){
    $block['content'] = custom_giggity_contents($delta);
  }
  return $block;
}

function custom_giggity_contents($delta){
  //Code that generates what goes into $block['content']
  return $output;
}
```

And I need to use something like this, and don't know how to incorporate it:

```
function giggity_contents() {
  $items['giggity'] = array(
    'title' => "Giggity",
    'page callback' => "show_giggity", //or custom_giggity_contents ;)
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'giggity.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Now I realize that the second block of code there might completely off, but I'm just using it as an example as to what I need to accomplish.

Edit: So this is what I'd like to accomplish, but I'm not sure how the $items callbacks work. I took this piece of code from a hook_menu() and replaced it with giggity_contents.

```
<?php

function custom_giggity_block_info(){
  $block['custom_giggity'] = array(
    'info' => t('Custom giggity'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $block;
}

function custom_giggity_block_view($delta = ''){
  $block = array();
  if($delta == 'custom_giggity'){
    $block['content'] = giggity_contents($delta);
  }
  return $block;
}

function giggity_contents() {
  $items['giggity'] = array(
    'title' => "Giggity",
    'page callback' => "custom_giggity_contents",
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'giggity.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
 return $items;
}
```

giggity.inc file:

```
 function custom_giggity_contents($delta){
  //Code that generates what goes into $block['content']
  return $output;
 }
```

Comment: the `page callback` can be whatever function callback you want. you just need to be sure to use `include once` or `require once` to include your `.inc` file with custom functions at the top of your module file.

Comment: @tenken mind to have a look again (above and below)? Not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like tenken said, use include_once at the top of the ".module" file like this:

```
<php
include_once drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/module_name.functions.inc';
?>
```

Comment: Is the answer staring me in the face? I can literally use the code I posted on the second block?

Comment: You want to replace 3 functions with 1 ? You can't, each hook has it's own purpose. If the question is another I don't understand it.

Comment: I realize that. I'm sorry, I didn't communicate very well. I added to my OP with what I'd like the result to look like.

Comment: It will work, you only need to include "giggity.inc" file at the top of "module_name.module" file as I did above, after that you can use those function eveywhere inside ".module" file, doesn't matter if you use them as callbacks or calling the functions directly.

Comment: Doesn't work. $block['content'] is getting array(
        'title' => "Giggity",
        'page callback' => "custom_giggity_contents",
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'giggity.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  ); as it's content.

Comment: If you use include_once in your module file then you no longer need `file => foo.inc`.

Comment: @tenken I was thinking it might come to that. My goal was to make drupal only load that file when the hook is called, instead of in the module file which is always loaded for enabled modules.

Comment: The functions in modules dont work that way. You're think PSR autoloading ..... this simply isn't that.